# Como adaptar meu código ao Android 4.1?

Tags: javascript, android, css

Estou fazendo um aplicativo usando o Materialize.
Mas está acontecendo um erro.

O MENU é pra funcionar como na segunda imagem. Ele está escondido com um `TranslateX(-100%)`. E quando eu clico no ícone de MENU ele abre o MENU.

Mas quando abro o aplicativo o MENU já aparece e pela metade. Não entendo como isso está acontecendo, visto que o MENU é feito com um `UL` e dentro tem os `LI's`.

Eu já uso `-webkit` nas propriedades.

A primeira imagem é como está e a segundo é como eu quero que seja. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta o código CSS, para alguém responder melhor.

Comment: ... livrarias e livrarias ... faz o seguinte... desenvolva o menu do jeito que vc queira q ele apareça ao estar aberto... depois vc simplesmente altera a width para 0, ai você chama uma function () para alterar o valor da largura como desejar, e vc ainda pode usar um transition pelo style em Javascript (já que essa è uma animação secundária)para dar um efeito legalzinho. Se não entendeu, me fala q eu venho com o codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei de responder uma questão similar, faça a adaptação do código e jogue o conteúdo do menu dentro da **`<div id="mySidenav"></div>`**. Creio que seja esse seu problema.
Jogue as funções do button para o seu botão de menu e voilá.